# Speed up query on mysql view

Tags: mysql

I have a very long query with multiple sub queries and this query can take up to 30 sec to complete.

Is there a better way to construct the query?

```
   select FROM_UNIXTIME(peg_remedy_incident.PEG_OutageStartTime,"%m-%d-%Y") AS 'Incident Date', PEG_Category AS Category, (select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe.Market ORDER BY Market)  from peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe WHERE peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe.IncidentVisibleID=peg_frm_inc_incidentXcustomerR.IncidentID AND peg_frm_inc_incidentXcustomerR.CustomerCode=peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe.CustomerCode AND peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe.RadioButton_Types IN (1,2) GROUP BY peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe.IncidentVisibleID, peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe.CustomerCode) AS Market,peg_frm_inc_incidentXcustomerR.CustomerName AS 'Customer' ,  peg_frm_inc_incidentXcustomerR.CustomerTicket AS 'Customer TT#', peg_remedy_incident.PEG_NetworkProvider AS 'Network Provider', peg_remedy_incident.PEG_ProviderTicketNumber AS 'Network Provider TT#', 
peg_remedy_incident.PEG_ThirdPartyVendor AS '3rd Party Support Vendor', peg_remedy_incident.PEG_ThirdPartyVendor_TT_ AS '3rd Party TT#','' AS 'Maintenance Window Outage? (Y/N)', TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM  peg_frm_inc_incidentXcustomerR.IncidentID) AS 'TT#',FROM_UNIXTIME(peg_remedy_incident.PEG_OutageStartTime,"%m-%d-%Y %r") AS `Event Start Time`, FROM_UNIXTIME(peg_remedy_incident.PEG_OutageStopTime,"%m-%d-%Y %r") AS `Event Stop Time`,
'=(M{ROWID}-L{ROWID})*1440' AS 'Total Minutes', '=(M{ROWID}-L{ROWID})' AS 'Total Hours/Minutes','=(M{ROWID}-L{ROWID})*R{ROWID}*1440' AS ' Total Outage Minutes','=(M{ROWID}-L{ROWID})*R{ROWID}' AS ' Total Outage Hours/Minutes',
(select count(DISTINCT(Site_ID)) from peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe WHERE peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe.IncidentVisibleID=peg_frm_inc_incidentXcustomerR.IncidentID AND peg_frm_inc_incidentXcustomerR.CustomerCode=peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe.CustomerCode AND peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe.RadioButton_Types=1) AS 'Outage Sites Impacted',
(select count(DISTINCT(Circuit_ID)) from peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe WHERE peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe.IncidentVisibleID=peg_frm_inc_incidentXcustomerR.IncidentID AND 
peg_frm_inc_incidentXcustomerR.CustomerCode=peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe.CustomerCode AND peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe.RadioButton_Types=1) AS 'Outage Circuits Impacted',
(select count(DISTINCT(Site_ID)) from peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe WHERE peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe.IncidentVisibleID=peg_frm_inc_incidentXcustomerR.IncidentID AND peg_frm_inc_incidentXcustomerR.CustomerCode=peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe.CustomerCode AND peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe.RadioButton_Types=2) AS 'Simplex Sites Impacted',
(select count(DISTINCT(Circuit_ID)) from peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe WHERE peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe.IncidentVisibleID=peg_frm_inc_incidentXcustomerR.IncidentID AND 
peg_frm_inc_incidentXcustomerR.CustomerCode=peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe.CustomerCode AND peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe.RadioButton_Types=2) AS 'Simplex Circuits Impacted',
 peg_remedy_incident.PEG_TechName AS 'Technician Dispatch', '' AS 'Summary & Ticket Notes', peg_remedy_incident.PEG_NetworkAvailabilityAffecti ,
CAST( CASE 
                WHEN peg_remedy_incident.PEG_Ring_Lateral = 'Lateral'
                     THEN 'Yes' 
                WHEN peg_remedy_incident.PEG_Ring_Lateral = 'Ring' 
                            THEN 'No'  
                            ELSE '' 
             END AS char(3)) as 'Lateral (Y/N)' ,
'' AS 'Backhaul/Non-Backhaul?', PEG_Resolution_Details AS 'Resolution Details',
PEG_CauseCode1 AS 'Cause Code 1', PEG_CauseCode2 AS 'Cause Code 2',
PEG_CauseCode3 AS 'Cause Code 3', PEG_CauseCode4 AS 'Cause Code 4', Root_Cause_Analysis AS 'Root Cause Analysis','' AS 'Notes',
(select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT peg_frm_inc_incidentXwork_log.Notes ORDER BY Request_ID) AS 'Work Log1' from peg_frm_inc_incidentXwork_log WHERE peg_frm_inc_incidentXwork_log.Incident_ID=peg_frm_inc_incidentXcustomerR.IncidentID  GROUP BY peg_frm_inc_incidentXwork_log.Incident_ID) as  'Work Log',
(select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe.Site_ID ORDER BY Site_ID) AS 'OutageSite List1' from peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe WHERE peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe.IncidentVisibleID=peg_frm_inc_incidentXcustomerR.IncidentID AND peg_frm_inc_incidentXcustomerR.CustomerCode=peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe.CustomerCode AND peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe.RadioButton_Types=1 GROUP BY peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe.IncidentVisibleID, peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe.CustomerCode) as  'Outage Site List'

FROM peg_frm_inc_incidentXcustomerR LEFT JOIN peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe ON peg_frm_inc_incidentXcustomerR.IncidentID=peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe.IncidentVisibleID
  LEFT JOIN peg_remedy_incident ON peg_frm_inc_incidentXcustomerR.IncidentID=peg_remedy_incident.PEG_VisibleTicketID WHERE peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe.RadioButton_Types IN(1 ,2) AND  peg_remedy_incident.PEG_VisibleTicketID>=000000000034000 GROUP BY peg_frm_inc_incidentXnetworkRe.IncidentVisibleID,peg_frm_inc_incidentXcustomerR.CustomerCode
```

Comment: First you start with [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) and then when you see which part of this ugly behemoth is problematic, you turn to optimizing your query or optimizing MySQL's settings. Please take a look at similar questions, they appear in the menu to the right. You'll see which details people are after.

Comment: *"Is there a better way to construct the query?"*: there certainly is a better way to format it. Moving to next question...

Comment: I wish I was smart as  you guys - I was lucky enough to get this query working the way it is...took me days...just trying to figure out to make it work smarter...but I am stuck.